# Problem with zsh_history file

Tags: zsh, command-history, macintosh, xdg

I am currently trying to clean up my home directory by following this [XDG BASE DIRECTORIES website](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/XDG_Base_Directory).

To do so, i have stored in my `~/.zshenv`:

```
# ---- Default editors ---- #
export EDITOR="nvim"
export VISUAL="nvim"

# ---- XDG BASE DIRECTORY ---- #
# https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/XDG_Base_Directory
export XDG_CONFIG_HOME=${XDG_CONFIG_HOME:="$HOME/.config"}
export XDG_CACHE_HOME=${XDG_CACHE_HOME:="$HOME/.cache"}
export XDG_DATA_HOME=${XDG_DATA_HOME:="$HOME/.local/share"}
export XDG_STATE_HOME=${XDG_STATE_HOME:="$HOME/.local/state"}

# ---- ZSH ---- #
export ZDOTDIR="$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/zsh"
export HISTFILE="$XDG_STATE_HOME/zsh/history"
export SHELL_SESSION_DIR="$XDG_STATE_HOME/zsh/sessions"
export SHELL_SESSION_FILE="$SHELL_SESSION_DIR/$TERM_SESSION_ID"
```

The problem is that when i `echo $HISTFILE`, it gives `~/.config/zsh/.zsh_history`, which is not what i want, and doesn't correspond to `$XDG_STATE_HOME/zsh/history`.

I tried adding `echo $HISTFILE` at the end of my `~/.zshenv` file, and it gives `~/.local/state/zsh/history`, which is exactly what i want. However, if i run `echo $HISTFILE` in terminal, it still gives `~/.config/zsh/.zsh_history`. So it seems like the `$HISTFILE` set in the `~/.zshenv` is not being used, **i don't understand why and how to fix it...**

The solution that i feel could work is to change the `/etc/zprofile` file, but i don't like doing, because i think that whenever i update my computer software, all those files get reset (I THINK...). If that is not the case, that i will modify them there to overwrite the `$HISTFILE`.

**But, if there is a better solution to the problem, please help.. (i would also like to know if the `/etc/zprofile`, `/etc/zshrc`,... files do indeed get reset when updating computer software, or not...)**

> By the way, I am not using `oh-my-zsh` and `zsh --version` is 5.8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I tried adding `echo $HISTFILE` at the end of my `~/.zshenv` file, and it gives `~/.local/state/zsh/history`, which is exactly what i want. However, if i run `echo $HISTFILE` in terminal, it still gives `~/.config/zsh/.zsh_history`. So it seems like the `$HISTFILE` set in the `~/.zshenv` is not being used

Perhaps it seems like that, but more likely, it's probably being overridden in one (or more!) of the following files, all of which are [sourced by Zsh *after* `~/.zshenv`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Files.html#Startup_002fShutdown-Files), in the order given here:

```bash
/etc/zprofile
$ZDOTDIR/.zprofile
/etc/zshrc
$ZDOTDIR/.zshrc
/etc/zlogin
$ZDOTDIR/.zlogin
```

The easiest way to discover exactly where it's overridden, is to start Zsh with

```bash
zsh --sourcetrace --verbose
```

This will

- print each file before it gets sourced (incl. files not sourced directly by Zsh) and
- print each command (incl. parameter assignments) before it gets evaluated.

---

> The solution that i feel could work is to change the `/etc/zprofile` file, but i don't like doing, because i think that whenever i update my computer software, all those files get reset (I THINK...).

As a rule, unless you are administering a server, you should generally not touch any of the files in `/etc`. If you don't like what's happening in your system's `/etc/z*` files, you have two options:

- To prevent Zsh from sourcing *any* `/etc/z*` files, start it with `zsh -d`.
- To prevent Zsh from sourcing `/etc/z*` files *other than `/etc/zshenv`,* add `setopt NO_globalrcs` to your `~/.zshenv`.

> i would also like to know if the `/etc/zprofile`, `/etc/zshrc`,... files do indeed get reset when updating computer software, or not...

Whenever you update macOS, they do indeed get reset. On other systems, they may or may not get reset whenever you update your Zsh package. It depends™ on how exactly the package is managed.

---

As an aside, please be aware that `~/.zshenv` gets sourced for every new shell, *including non-interactive shells.* Conversely, Zsh sources `$ZDOTDIR/.zprofile` for login shells only, whereas `$ZDOTDIR/.zshrc`, on the other hand, Zsh sources for every *interactive* shell.

Apple’s Terminal.app starts a login shell whenever  you open a new window or tab. Most Linux terminals, however don’t start login shells this shells this way, unless you configure them to do so. If you want your Zsh dotfiles to be portable, then it's best to assume that Zsh is started as a login shell only on macOS.

Given that info, I would recommend you to reorganize your global variable assignments as follows:

`$HOME/.zshenv`:

```bash
# No need to export anything here, as .zshenv is sourced for 
# _every_ shell (unless invoked with `zsh -f`).

# Assign these only if they don't have value yet. 
: ${XDG_CONFIG_HOME:=$HOME/.config}
: ${XDG_STATE_HOME:=~/.local/state}

# Set $ZDOTDIR here to be able to store your other Zsh dotfiles 
# outside of $HOME. 
ZDOTDIR=$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/zsh
```

`$ZDOTDIR/.zprofile`:

```
# The following have to go in .zprofile, because they are used by 
# macOS's /etc/zshrc file, which is sourced _before_ your`.zshrc` 
# file.
export SHELL_SESSION_DIR=$XDG_STATE_HOME/zsh/sessions
export SHELL_SESSION_FILE=$SHELL_SESSION_DIR/$TERM_SESSION_ID
```

`$ZDOTDIR/.zshrc`:

```bash
# HISTFILE is used by interactive shells only. Plus, 
# non-interactive shells & external commands don't need this var. 
# Hence, we put it in your .zshrc file, since that's sourced for 
# each interactive shell, and don't export it.
HISTFILE=$XDG_STATE_HOME/zsh/history

# Only vars used by external commands or non-interactive sub 
# shells need to be exported. Note that you can export vars 
# without assigning values to them.
export XDG_CONFIG_HOME XDG_STATE_HOME
export XDG_CACHE_HOME=~/.cache
export XDG_DATA_HOME=~/.local/share
export EDITOR=nvim VISUAL=nvim
```

Comment: First of all, thank you. I moved the `HISTFILE` to my `.zshrc` and the problem was fixed. But because of your great answer i am confused on what should actually go in the `.zshenv` file, because i read online that it should set `$PATH`, `$PAGER`, or `$EDITOR`. But you moved the `EDITOR`, `VISUAL` and `SUDO_EDITOR` to `.zprofile` so i am confused...

Comment: And also, i also have other variables like `NVIMDOTDIR=$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/nvim`. Should i put those in the `.zshenv` like `ZDOTDIR` or should i put them in another file?

Comment: All vars needed by external commands should be exported. Exports should be done in `.zprofile` only, to set them in the login shell. Once they are exported to the environment, all other shells will auto-import them. Despite the word `env` in its name,  `.zshenv` is not the place where you should put any env vars.

Comment: Also, if you set `$PATH` in `~/.zshenv`, then it can easily be overridden by one of the `/etc/z*` files, as happened with `$HISTFILE`. In general, the only thing you ever need to put in in `.zshenv` is `$ZDOTDIR`. The only reason I added XDG vars there, too, is because it’s, in this case, convenient for reuse.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @MarlonRichert In your recommendations `$ZDOTDIR/.zprofile` sets `$SHELL_SESSION_DIR ` w/ a reference to `$XDG_STATE_HOME`, which is set & exported in `$ZDOTDIR/.zshrc`. However you say in the comment that `$ZDOTDIR/.zprofile` is sourced *before* `$ZDOTDIR/.zshrc`. This seems contradictory, can you clarify?

Comment: @JoshuaSkrzypek You’re right, that was a mistake. Thanks, I’ve updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Handling those user preferences isn't `~/.zshenv`'s job, but `~/.zshrc`'s

Try editing the rc file instead of env to avoid system defaults being applied after the fact.

I myself apply a completely different location for my zsh settings files in env (i.e., not ~), but then write those specific settings in profile and rc depending on whether I want them sourced just at login or every time I open a new interactive session.

Order matters. Cheers!